# SQL: Specifying a unique constraint through a foreign key and efficiently querying it

Tags: mysql, sql, database, laravel, database-schema

## The Schema

I have the following database schema in MySQL:

#### topics

- id: PK
- name: string, unique
- slug: string, unique

e.g. `(5, Algebra, algebra), (6, Java, java) ...`

#### module_sections

- id: PK
- topic_id: FK => topics.id
- name: string
- order: unsigned integer, indexed
- unique([topic_id, name])

e.g.

`(1, 5, Algebra Basics, 1),
(2, 6, Introduction to Programming, 1),
(3, 6, Variables, 2) ...`

#### module

- id: PK
- module_section_id: FK => module_sections.id
- name: string
- slug: string
- order: unsigned integer, indexed
- unique([module_section_id, name])
- !PROBLEM: unique([module_section.topic_id, slug])

e.g. 
`(1, 1, Collecting like terms, collecting-like-terms, 1),
(2, 2, What is Programming?, what-is-programming, 1),
(3, 2, Installing Java, installing-java, 2) ...`

## Database Schema Explained

The above database shows 3 tables. Each `topic` has many `module_sections` and each `module_sections` has many `modules`.

The above example data can be written in a list like so:

- Algebra

  - Algebra Basics

    - Collecting Like Terms
- Java

  - Introduction to Programming

    - What is Programming?
    - Installing Java
  - Variables

Each `topic` must have a unique `name` and `slug` in the table.

Each `module section` must have a unique `name` for that `topic`. (e.g. we can have a section called `Introduction` in both `Algebra` and `Java` as they are both separate topics)

Each `module` must be unique for that `topic` (not just for that section). For example we cannot have the module `What is Programming?` under both `Introduction to Programming` AND `Variables` (as they are both in the same topic), but we can have `Arithmetic` under both `Algebra Basics` and `Introduction to Programming` (as they are in different topics). Unfortunately I was not able to specify this specific constraint in the Schema.

## Queries

I wish to perform the following queries efficiently:

- Getting a `topic` through it's slug (I managed to do this)
- Listing all the `module sections` and `modules` of a specific `topic` through the topics slug  ordered correctly (I managed to do this)
- Retrieving a module from using the `topic slug` and `module slug`. For example: if topic slug is "java" and module slug is "installing-java" it should return the record with PK 3 in `modules`. (I do not know how to do this efficiently)

## The Problems

To summarise, the problems I am facing are the following:

- How to specify the integrity constraint: `unique([module_section.topic_id, slug])` in the `modules` table.
- Retrieving a module from using the `topic slug` and `module slug`

Feel free to suggest changes to schema provided it:

- maintains integrity constraints
- queries can be performed efficiently

I am using Laravel for the PHP framework.

Comment: You give four columns in your description of table `module_sections`, but the sample data has five.

Comment: good catch. updated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to specify the integrity constraint: unique([module_section.topic_id, slug]) in the modules table.

You can't.  SQL does not support indirect constraints such as that.  You can constrain only the values that appear directly in the table to which the constraint applies.

Your issue arises from your choice to use single-column surrogate keys, combined with the fact that your requirements for slug uniqueness are not congruent with your requirements for module uniqueness.  With such a structure, there is no way to express an SQL constraint such as you want to place.  As an alternative, you could create insert and update triggers on the `module` table that enforce the wanted condition on module slugs.

On the other hand, you could write a constraint such as you imagine if the PK of `module_section` were composite, with `topic_id` as one of its columns.  Then the FK in `module` that references the module's section would include in it the topic id, and you could use a constraint to achieve what you're after.

Comment: That makes sense, but can you suggest any edits I can make to the schema or method I am doing this such that I can satisfy my constraints and perform efficient queries.

Comment: @YahyaUddin - I already suggested *two* possible alternatives.  They have different trade-offs for performance of the query you imagine, for other queries, and for data manipulation.  Personally, I'm inclined to avoid triggers as much as possible, but I'm in no position to judge which is the overall best approach for you.